# How to convert a XML culture/locale?

Tags: xml, localization, internationalization, globalization

I have a XML where all values are stringified accordingly to a given culture (decimal separator for floats, month/day order for dates).

I have to convert this XML to another culture. How to do that with minimal effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is a transition format, so it is best to keep it in culture-invariant format. I wouldn't recommend formatting XML.

That said, if you still have to do that, because of somebody's strange requirement, you will have to parse each string to appropriate class and format it again using different culture. I can't actually give you an example, as I don't know what language/technology you are referring to. I can only assume that you meant C#/.Net...

**EDIT**

---

You can also transform culture-invariant XML [using XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796515/how-to-get-current-country-code-locale-in-xsl/797294#797294).

Comment: I agree with this suggestion. Just stick to the formats (for e.g. the date and dateTime formats) provided by the XML Schema Definition standard as XML is mainly for system to system

Comment: ł I don´t have control over the XML generation. I can do as you said in C# or any other language, but I was looking for a shortcut that involved less programming.